# NullReferenceException in HttpHandler with WaitHandle

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a legacy web forms application with a long-polling IHttpAsyncHandler that's started to raise exceptions in the event log with precious little information. I can reproduce the error in IIS express if a long-polling XMLHttpRequest is pending and I make a change to web.config. This recycles the process and in the debugger and event log it raises the same NullReferenceException:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 05/06/2020 2:30:09 PM 
Event time (UTC): 05/06/2020 6:30:09 PM 
Event ID: c8428fb2935c47be90ebc6a7849063e6 
Event sequence: 7 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/WebApp-2-132358551451863719 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /WebApp 
    Application Path: C:\Users\naask\source\repos\WebApp\ 
    Machine name: DESKTOP-S7T1J31 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 11892 
    Process name: iisexpress.exe 
    Account name: DESKTOP-S7T1J31\naask 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:48061/WebApp/edits?id=~/somepath.aspx/26264&wait=true 
    Request path: /WebApp/edits 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: DESKTOP-S7T1J31\naask 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 6 
    Thread account name: DESKTOP-S7T1J31\naask 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details:
```

In the debugger, it tries and fails to load the symbol information:

[image: Source not found]

The exception information matches the event log data:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
```

Presumably the symbols I'm looking for are in System.Web, but I have those symbols loaded and I've [setup VS to debug framework code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2019):

[image]

I'm not sure where to go from here to debug the problem with the IHttpAsyncHandler. The long-polling handler uses `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` on a Semaphore to await an event, and it releases all the waiters simultaneously when that event occurs. I only see these errors after the AppPool recycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a way to fix the missing source issues to debug this, but after some exhaustive case reduction, the source of the problem was a path through the IHttpAsyncHandler where the IAsyncResult being returned was null.